# Variable issue with PHP

Tags: php, debugging, variables

I'm coding some PHP app and I'm receving some strange values from my code, example:

```
//Loop here lot of intval because i tried a lot of things
$testval=intval(intval($i/$dayspromo[$key])*$dayspromo[$key]);
echo "<br> val $testval counter $i bool<br>";
var_dump($i);
var_dump($testval);
var_dump($i-$testval);




 echo "<br> again val ".$testval." y ".$i-$testval." comp <br>";
```

will print at `$i=9:`

```
val 8 counter 9 bool
int(9) int(8) int(1) -8 comp
```

As you can see something very bad happened, if i try to subtract $testval from $i i will get wrong values but var_dump will show the RIGHT value. Also first part of the second echo is missing and i don't know why.

How do i fix or debug this to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is `$r` defined, and what is it?

Comment: ah sorry pasted old one, that's not part of the code i just tried to copy $testvar to $r and didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

please try this:

```
echo "<br> again val ".$testval." y ".($i-$testval)." comp <br>";
```

if you forget the brackets it will happen something like this:

```
$string = "hello world"; // you have a string

$tmp = $string - 10; // substract 10 from string
// string will be converted to int and this is zero
// zero minus 10 is -10
```

Comment: oh yes my bad.... that leads me to another question for my code as $testval<$i will work only for $testval==$i. I think i will open a new question